# How to force reload with firefox via javascript

Tags: javascript, url, firefox, reload

My webpage reads the URL to load frames in it. For example:

```
https://luis.impa.br/?=meteor
```

loads the weather conditions of my city on the right frame. This is done through javascript that reads the URL with `window.location.search.substring(1).split("?")`, and opening a page in a frame.

In Google Chrome everything works just fine. Yet, in Firefox, if I do a C-Shift-R, the page reloads normally, but if I press the Reload button near the address bar, the page does not reload properly (you can see the spinner failing to stop).

Is there any way to force Firefox (maybe with javascript?) to fully reload the page when pressing the reload button?

Comment: So you're saying page is not reloading when you press `C+Shift+R` ?

Comment: I don't you if that can help you, but Firefox shows up an error when pressing the reload button: **NaN value for x1, x2, y1, y2 on line 431 of markup.js**.

Comment: @E-telier: I once in a while see that too, but no idea what it is. There is no markup.js in my page.

Comment: @semperlabs: No, I am saying the opposite. It is the reload button that does not work properly.

Comment: @luis-a-florit It seems there is a bug in Firefox : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1419412 ... I don't know if your problem is caused by this.